# Sqoop import from MariaDB into HBase with custom row keys

Tags: java, mysql, import, hbase, sqoop

I'm using Sqoop to import columns from a MySQL table into a HBase table and I want to add a field to the row key that isn't a column.

I know you can set composite row keys with:

```
sqoop import ... --hbase-row-key <col1>,<col2>
```

but I want something like < custom value >_< col1 >_< col2 >.

If sqoop import doesn't allow it, is it possible to edit the row keys afterward to add that field ?